# Can't get element id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive, where I'm trying to get the element and attribute id, but I'm getting undefined.

Code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clientApp')

.directive('myVideo', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="border:solid 10px gray; width:auto;">'+
              '<video style="width:100%; height:auto;" controls>'+
              '<source src="views/unit_1.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video">'+
              '</video>'+
              '{{test}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log('Elements', elem.id);
      console.log('Attributes', attrs.id);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute specifies a `unique id` for an HTML element.It is mostly used to point to a `style in stylesheet`, and by `JavaScript to manipulate the DOM elements` with the specific id.

The `id` property sets or returns the id of an element (the value of an element's id attribute).

So, as per the requirement you have to define the `id` attribute in your directive attribute.

```
<div my-video id="videoId"></div>
```

Hence, when you will log the console with these code of lines it will return you the value of an `id` attribute.

```
console.log('Elements', elem.id);      // 'Elements', videoId
console.log('Attributes', attrs.id);   // 'Attributes', videoId
```

Answer (score 3):

`id` is nothing but attribute present on directive, so you can access attributes collection directly inside `link` function 3rd parameter(`attrs`). Though you can apply @Phil suggested answer.

But in your case what I think is, you should have `id` attribute on your directive element, then only you can only see it console.

```
<div my-video id="myId"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the directive `link` function, `elem` is a jqLite object (or jQuery if included) so you would use something like

```
elem.prop('id')
```

or

```
elem.attr('id')
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: `elem.attr` thing, still I feel `attrs.id` seems easier +1

Comment: @PankajParkar depends what you're after. The `attrs` property has some [extra awesome in it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) but for normal attribute properties, it's about the same